# How to remove (or hide) Chat Status Icons from Messaging Menu

Tags: unity, indicator, messaging-menu

I would know how to remove or hide in Ubuntu 12.04 the [Chat Status section](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu#Chat_status_section) (available, away, busy, invisible and offline) from Messaging Menu as I am not using any instant messenger. I do not want to remove the entire menu, just that section.

Thank you very much and best regards!!

[image: Chat status section screenshot]

Answer (score 15):

## FOR 12.04

[If you're using 13.10 or newer see here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/421451/44179).

---

### Its possible...

[image: pic]

As you can see the status section has been removed leaving just the Broadcast and Mail sections

To put a positive spin - open-source means you have direct access to the actual source-code.  You can interrogate and change the code ... as long as you give back the code changes to others!

So here goes - the following demonstrates the code changes that are required to the package `indicator-messages`

#### prerequisites

Lets get source packages from the repository:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-messages
apt-get source indicator-messages
```

This will create a folder - name will change depending upon the package version of `indicator-messages`.  For 12.04 this folder is `indicator-messages-0.6.0`

#### code changes

Two modules in the folder `indicator-messages-0.6.0` will need changing.

```
cd indicator-messages-0.6.0/src
```

**status-items.c**

Using your favourite editor add the line `return NULL;` at or around line 80 in the function "status_items_build" shown:

[image: pic2]

**messages-service.c**

At or around line 893 in the function "resort_menu" comment out the code shown with `/*` and `*/`

[image: pic3]

#### lets compile

To compile this, move up to the parent folder

```
cd ..
```

Compile, make and install:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Logout and login.

#### to undo

To undo your changes:

```
cd indicator-messages-0.6.0
sudo make uninstall
sudo apt-get --reinstall install indicator-messages
```

Comment: +1 Fantastic answer. The 'undo' bit is much appreciated too.

Answer (score 4):

### For 13.10

[If you're using for 12.04 see here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/281833/44179)

---

Almost same steps in [How to remove (or hide) Chat Status Icons from Messaging Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185021/how-to-remove-or-hide-chat-status-icons-from-messaging-menu)

- Install build prerequisites

  ```
  sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-messages
  ```
- Download source archive

  ```
  apt-get source indicator-messages
  ```
- Modify `src/im-desktop-menu.c`, add `/*` and `*/`  to comment non needed menu as it is shown here:

  ```
  /*
  static GMenu *
  create_status_section (void)
  {
    GMenu *menu;
    GMenuItem *item;
  ...
      g_object_unref (item);
      return menu;
  }
  */

  /*
    {
      GMenu *status_section;

      status_section = create_status_section();
      im_menu_append_section (IM_MENU (menu), G_MENU_MODEL (status_section));

      g_object_unref (status_section);
    }
  */
  ```

  To remove `Clear` menu item too:

  ```
  /*
    {
      GMenu *clear_section;

      clear_section = g_menu_new ();
      g_menu_append (clear_section, _("Clear"), "indicator.remove-all");
      im_menu_append_section (IM_MENU (menu), G_MENU_MODEL (clear_section));

      g_object_unref (clear_section);
    }
  */
  ```
- Compile

  ```
  ./autogen.sh
  ./configure
  make
  ```
- Install

  ```
  sudo make install
  ```

  Or like me I just replace it, without un-installing original  (I use 64bit):

  Backup original

  ```
  sudo mv /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service_orig
  ```

  Copy the new compiled version

  ```
  sudo cp ./src/indicator-messages-service /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service_mod
  ```

  Create a link to the new compiled version

  ```
  sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service_mod /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/indicator-messages/indicator-messages-service
  ```

---

### For 14.04

[If you're using for 12.04 see here.](https://askubuntu.com/a/281833/44179)

Same steps as 13.10 with different modifications

---

- Modify `src/im-desktop-menu.c`, add `/*` and `*/`  to comment non needed menu as it is shown here:

  ```
  /*
  static void
  menu_append_status (GMenu       *menu,
                              const gchar *label,
                      const gchar *detailed_action,
                      const gchar *icon_name)
  {
    GMenuItem *item;
    GIcon *icon;
  ...

    g_object_unref (icon);
    g_object_unref (item);
  }

  static void
  im_desktop_menu_show_chat_section (ImDesktopMenu *menu)
  {
            GMenu *status_section;
  ...
    menu->status_section_visible = TRUE;

    g_object_unref (status_section);
  }
  */
  ...

  /*
    if (g_desktop_app_info_get_boolean (app_info, "X-MessagingMenu-UsesChatSection"))
      im_desktop_menu_show_chat_section (menu);
  */
  ```

Comment: I had to `sudo ./autogen.sh` because there's no ./configure file. This made me use `sudo chmod 777 * -R && sudo chmod 777 .* -R` in the indicator-messages folder to get the rights for `make`

Comment: `./autogen.sh` should work without sudo. It didn't work for you?  weird! or you may called `apt-get source indicator-messages` with `sudo`?

Comment: oh yes ! I did that with sudo in the download

Comment: Ok, so it works with the package-installation method, going to try your replace-only solution just to see. Your bounty is up in 19 hours (please comment if I haven't given in like 24-48h) :)

Comment: do you think I also can remove `*clear_section` (which is, I think, the "clear the notifications") ?

Comment: Yeah it seems to work, as it pass in compilation.

Comment: I just tried it. It works fine (commenting out `*clear_section`) and installing the modified package with `cp` also works. I have a question though : i didn't follow your example and I directly copied indicator-messages-service in /urs/lib/.../indicator-messages-service, without using the `ln -s`. Why did you wanted me to create a symbolic link exactly ? For the updates ?

Comment: Yep, updates, I want keep my modification tracked and away from default installation. As you can hold(pin) that package.

Comment: Yeah well `hold` makes me mad about the `X packages to be installed`, X being the number of packages I've hold. It tells me that every time I update. If you have an idea to `hold`without `apt-get` bitchin about that, it also is one of my questions in another thread.

Comment: The solution works! Ubuntu 13.10 64-bit here. Thanks a lot for the tutorial. :)

Comment: I just installed Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit and tried to do the following steps, but the first part to be commented (that first block in grey) is missing in the src/im-desktop-menu.c file. The second part (second block) exists. I did this when I was using 13.10 and it worked perfectly. Please, any thoughts? Thanks. :)

Comment: @brunces, seem there were some code changes after 14.04 beta. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Cool, Sneetsher. It worked. Thanks for your attention. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the indicator-messages package from software center for completely remove it or see [this link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MessagingMenu) to configure it for your needs .

Comment: Thanks, I've already read this article before but I have not found what I wanted. I mean if there is any way to remove or hide the IM status icons but still use Messaging Menu for other applications like thunderbird or polly.

Comment: You can completely remove it and use application specific system tray icon instead.

Comment: Is that possible? A specific system tray icon to manage Thunderbird, Polly, Skype, and U1 at the same time?

Comment: I do not know about all your favorite program but for example i use pidgin as my messenger and i active it's system tray icon in it's setting and do not have any problem.

Comment: I see what you mean. But I don't like it... Thunderbird and Ubuntu One are default's Ubuntu apps so they are very integrated with the system and Polly (Twitter client) also uses the same technology. Skype goes free and you need an extra package, skype-wrapper. Anyways, I just was wondering the possibility, but if it's no possible I'm not going to die for... :-D Really, thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: Your welcome, see this link, it might help you: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/12/remove-unused-entries-from-the-ubuntu-messaging-menu

Comment: @user44849 If you get your answer, accept this answer for your question.