# How to remove chat icons from messaging menu in 13.10 saucy

Tags: 13.10, indicator, messaging-menu

Upgrading from 13.04, the chat items (Available,Away,Busy,Invisible,Offline) re-appeared in the messaging-menu. I use Pidgin for chat, the icons do not reflect pidgin status changes. For Thunderbird I want to keep the envelope.

I already tried:

```
sudo apt-get remove empathy*
sudo apt-get remove gwibber*
sudo apt-get remove telepathy-indicator
```

I never had to change and recompile the messaging/indicator code as suggested e.g. in  [How to remove (or hide) Chat Status Icons from Messaging Menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185021/how-to-remove-or-hide-chat-status-icons-from-messaging-menu)

Comment: Did you reboot?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove (or hide) Chat Status Icons from Messaging Menu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185021/how-to-remove-or-hide-chat-status-icons-from-messaging-menu)

Comment: detailed question addressing possible duplicate