# How to remove "Ubuntu Help" and "About This Computer" from shutdown menu? (indicator-session applet)

Tags: 13.10, indicator

I need to remove from shutdown menu:

- "About This Computer"
- "Ubuntu Help"

I've been trying to figure out how, and I looked around on-line, but couldn't find anything.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Build from source, same method as https://askubuntu.com/a/421451/44179 (I have tested this in Ubuntu 14.04, but it should work for 13.10 too)

- Install build prerequisites

  ```
  sudo apt-get build-dep indicator-session
  ```
- Download source

  ```
  apt-get source indicator-session
  ```
- Comment non-needed menu section `create_admin_section`, using `/*`,`*/` and `//`:

  ```
  /*
  static GMenuModel *
  create_admin_section (void)
  {
    return NULL;
    GMenu * menu;

    menu = g_menu_new ();
    g_menu_append (menu, _("About This Computer"), "indicator.about");
            g_menu_append (menu, _("Ubuntu Help"), "indicator.help");
    return G_MENU_MODEL (menu);
  }
  */
  ```

  ...

  ```
    if (profile == PROFILE_DESKTOP)
      {
        //sections[n++] = create_admin_section ();
        sections[n++] = create_settings_section (self);
  ```

  ...

  ```
    if (sections & SECTION_ADMIN)
      {
        //rebuild_section (desktop->submenu, 0, create_admin_section());
      }
  ```
- Build and install

  ```
  cd ./indicator-session-12.10.5+14.04.20140311.1/
  mkdir build
  cd build/
  cmake ..
  make

  sudo make install
  ```

  [image]